# issue with the org.testng.testNg

Tags: java, testng

when am trying to run the xml file from cmd it is showing error as "could not load class/main org.testng.TestNG"
[error iamge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOgSF.png)

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng) says:

> Assuming that you have TestNG in your class path

So, jsut configure your classpath. You have to add your test classes too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run testng.xml file from cmd Please try the following command.

E:\ProjectFolder>java -cp E:\lib*;E:\ProjectFolder\bin org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

Where E:\ProjectFolder is your current project folder and testng.xml file will be present here.

E:\lib is the location where your all dependent jar files are present.

E:\ProjectFolder\bin is the location where your all codes are present.

Comment: no its not working..i tried with the same as you have suggested

Comment: 3 points need to keep in mind.... 1. need to copy all jars ( -cp E:\lib\*)...2. Give the path of your bin folder where your all test cases are present.....3. testng.xml file should be present in current directory from where you are executing the command. All this three command need to execute in a single command. .... still if you face issue please share the screenshot.